# DF equation: solve for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image]

OK, i know what to do with the first and second term. Could someone please help with the third and solve for x? **:)** [This might seem a *silly* question though.]

Comment: If only there was $\frac{2x}{1-x^2}$ as the argument for the third term=)

Comment: I know right!:D @TZakrevskiy

Comment: What did you do with the first and second terms ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici OK,something like first term - 6 tan^-1 x and second like pi-2 tan^-1 x. I m not sure though.

Comment: What is DF? (in the title)

Comment: I agree with @TZakrevskiy, shouldn't there be a minus-sign in the denominator of the third term? Are you absolutely sure this is not a typo? Then the substitution of $x=tan(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)$ clears up the whole equation, using doubling formulas.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Oops!I meant Differential eqn. Hehe guess that's a _misnomer_

Comment: @Nicky Hekster: Even i would prefer the question being a _typo_. :D

Comment: @mathgeek OK then with the substitution of $x=tan(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)$ the equation reduces to $sin(\alpha)=tan(\frac{1}{6}\pi - \alpha)$.

Comment: _Nicky_, I don't actually get you. Could you try answering the sum as a whole,i mean _answer_ it rather than commenting here and i'd accept that. **:)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $x=tan(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)$. Then:

$\large \frac{2x}{1+x^2}= \frac{2tan(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)}{1+tan^2(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)}= \frac{2cos(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)sin(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)}{cos^2(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)+sin^2(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)}=\frac{sin(\alpha)}{1}= \normalsize sin(\alpha)$.

And

$\large \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}= \frac{1-tan^2(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)}{1+tan^2(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)}= \frac{cos^2(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)-sin^2(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)}{cos^2(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)+sin^2(\frac{1}{2}\alpha)}=\frac{cos(\alpha)}{1} = \normalsize cos(\alpha)$.

Plugging this into the equation we get:

$3sin^{-1}(sin(\alpha))-cos^{-1}(cos(\alpha))+2tan^{-1}(sin(\alpha))=\pi/3 \Leftrightarrow$

$3\alpha-\alpha +2tan^{-1}(sin(\alpha))=\pi/3 \Leftrightarrow$

$sin(\alpha)=tan(\pi/6-\alpha)$.    $(*)$

From this point you have to solve this equation numerically (for example use [this](http://www.meta-calculator.com/online/) graphical calculator).

For example $\alpha=0.266284..$ is a solution and hence $x=0.13393434..$ is an approximate solution. Of course I am a bit imprecise, since there are restrictions to the solution of $(*)$ (for example $-1 \leq tan(\pi/6-\alpha) \leq 1$) and taking periodicity of trigoniometric functions into account. I leave that to you.